# Bug on wall identification request

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've been finding a few of these on the same wall of my apartment the path month. Size is maybe 3-5 mm.

I live in an apartment in Toronto Canada.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without clearer photos it is pretty hard to say, however, I think it is likely to be one of the [Dermestidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae) family of beetles.

These include a bunch of common pests in the household, including "[carpet beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrenus)" (*Anthrenus* sp.), and the [larder beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestes_lardarius) (*Dermestes lardarius*).

I think this is most likely to be a carpet beetle, given the light/dark mottled pattern on the shell.